# Why is my code causing my component to show up for a split second?

Tags: react-native, react-component, jwt, stack-navigator

I am developing an application for a religious group, and I just implemented AsyncStorage to store the JWT received from my back end. My back end is working perfectly, and I'm able to store and delete the token on login/register and logout. But when the app is refreshed, it shows the login screen for a split second.

Here is my action:

```
export const fetchUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const token = await getData();

    const reqObj = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    if (token) {
      dispatch({ type: "IS_LOADING_JWT" });
      fetch(`http://${IP_ADDRESS}:4000/api/v1/auto_login`, reqObj)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((current_user) => {
          dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: current_user });
          dispatch({ type: "NOT_LOADING_JWT" });
        });
    }
  };
};
```

Here is my helper function to retrieve the stored value-key pair:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt");
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

This is my user reducer:

```
const user = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return action.user;

    case "LOGOUT_USER":
      return null;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default user;
```

Here is my 'authentication flow' with my stack navigator:

```
class Navigator extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {this.props.jwtLoader ? (
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              title: "",
              headerShown: false,
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="loader" component={LoaderScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : !this.props.user ? (
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              title: "",
              headerShown: false,
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              title: "",
              headerShown: false,
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

My jwtLoader:

```
const jwtLoader = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "IS_LOADING_JWT":
      return true;

    case "NOT_LOADING_JWT":
      return false;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default jwtLoader;
```

My theory is that there is a delay on dispatching the action. That is why I believe my Login component shows for a split second.

I have already tried getting and setting my user during my SplashScreen load, but that doesn't work either.

Here is a demo video: [Text](https://youtu.be/xbWmePjB8pI)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try fetching user from the `constructor` instead of `componentDidMount`?

Comment: I've tried that... it still has the same bug. 

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.fetchUser();
  }

Comment: What's your initial state?

Comment: My initial state is in my reducer, user is equal to null. Once the fetch gets a successful response, it sends out a dispatch to set the user.

Comment: How about `this.props.jwtLoader`, where does it come from?

Comment: the jwtLoader is just a redux state of false or true. It just a loading screen. Ill update my question with the code.

Comment: So, when you open your app, your `jwtLoader` is `false` and `user` is `null`. Following the logic of your stack navigator, you get to the login screen. Try using `true` as a default value for `jwtLoader`.

Comment: That seems to work when there is a user in my state. But when I log out, I delete the token, and clear the user state. So loader will always be true. This causes the app to stay stuck in my loader.

Comment: Try this:


export const fetchUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_LOADING_JWT" });
    const token = await getData();
    const reqObj = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    if (token) {
      
      fetch(`http://${IP_ADDRESS}:4000/api/v1/auto_login`, reqObj)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((current_user) => {
          dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: current_user });
        });
    }

   dispatch({ type: "NOT_LOADING_JWT" });
  };
};

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to properly format code in the comment section